# LuaLaTeX Error: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'nextcluster')

Tags: luatex

I have a strange problem, and currently no starting point how I could solve this. Maybe someone here has an idea.

When compiling my documente I get the error message:

```
ERROR: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'nextcluster')
```

I was able to narrow down the cause to two words that occur in my document, once "Hauswänden" (german for house walls) and once "Bevölkerung" (german for population). Below I have a sample document. When either of the commented out lines are included again, the above message occurs.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}


\begin{document}

Dieser Satz funktioniert.

Dieser Satz ebenfalls.

%Doch wenn das Wort Hauswänden im Satz vorkommt geht es nicht.

%Beim Wort Bevölkerung funktioniert es ebenfalls nicht.

Die Fehlermeldung Lautet:

ERROR: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'nextcluster')

\end{document}
```

compiled with: LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (MiKTeX 21.1)

Comment: It is a bug in the harfbuzz discretionary handling and I will report it forward. For  you the best is not to use polyglossia, but only babel.

Comment: I get no error with TeX Live 2020 (LuaHBTeX 1.12.0) or 2021/pretest (LuaHBTeX 1.13.0) But I don't have `cambria.ttc`, only the `.ttf` files.

Comment: Marcel already fixed it: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/179

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Thank you very much, when I do not use polyglissia it works.