# Strange error when compiling document with Cambria font using lualatex in TeX Live 2021

Tags: fonts, errors, luatex, polyglossia, luaotfload

The following LaTeX document results in this error when compiled with lualatex in TeX Live 2021.

```
warning  (node filter): error: ...exmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-ha
rf-plug.lua:455: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'nextclust
er')
```

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Cambria}

\begin{document}

utgåv

\end{document}
```

The document is really as minimal as I managed to make it and still reproduce the error.
For example, if I change `polyglossia` to `fontspec`, everything works fine.
If I change the (Windows) font `Cambria` to `Calibri`, everything works fine.
And even if I change a few of the letters in the text `utgåv`, everything works fine!

So what’s going on? Is the error in `polyglossia`, the font or in `luaotfload`?
And how to fix it?
BTW, similar code used to work fine in TeX Live 2020.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587124/lualatex-error-attempt-to-perform-arithmetic-on-a-nil-value-field-nextcluster : It is a luaotfload bug which will be fixed with the next luaotfload release.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcelKrüger. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will mark it as ‘accepted’. I have tested the patch to `luaotfload-harf-plug.lua` from https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/commit/97a89d691db2a7ee0ead56eafa517f74d6a5dea2, and it fixed the problem. Too bad it didn’t get included in TeX Live 2021. 