# lualatex with devanagari script crashes with a particulal string

Tags: luatex, devanagari

I made a document to print the word "बालिका" but lualatex crashes. Actually, it works until "बालि". The addition of "क" is enough to make it crash. It looks like a bug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\babelprovide[mapdigits,maparabic,import,main]{hindi}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{sf}{chandas}
\babelfont[*devanagari]{rm}[Language=Default]{shobhika}
\babelfont[english]{sf}{FreeSans}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
बालिका
\end{document}
```

There are weird tricks to avoid the crash like adding two newlines above with random latin letters. Also if i remove [*devanagari] it'll work but then ligatures ( प्र क्र प्त ... ) are not supported. The same problem occurs with polyglossia.

here is the crash log:

```
Package babel Info: The following font families will use the default
(babel)             settings for all or some languages:
(babel)             * \rmfamily = lmr
(babel)               [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;
(babel)             * \ttfamily = lmtt
(babel)               [lmmono10-regular]:
(babel)             There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but
(babel)             'babel' will no set Script and Language, which could
(babel)             be relevant in some languages. If your document uses
(babel)             these families, consider redefining them with \babelfont.
(babel)             Reported on input line 3.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

Package fontspec Warning: Font 'FreeSans' is using the
(fontspec)                default features for language 'English'.
(fontspec)                That's usually fine, because many languages
(fontspec)                require no specific features, but if the output is
(fontspec)                not as expected, consider selecting another font.


warning  (node filter): error: ...exmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-ha
rf-plug.lua:455: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'nextcluster')

.
\newpage ...k \@nobreakfalse \everypar {}\fi \par 
                                                  \ifdim \prevdepth >\z@ \vs...

l.20 \end{document}
```

Comment: I got a chandas.ttf from http://www.sanskritweb.net/cakram/  and it ran without error in texlive 2021 [the output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqP9j.png) but I am not sure if that is right as I can not read the script.

Comment: you should probably show the full log, so package versions are shown I can then compare with the version here

Comment: it should be fixed in a current luaotfload, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/587124/2388

Comment: i temporarily modified the buggy file in my installation, it works.